# Is there a defined behavior of the current program that is running when our ssh exits?

Tags: bash, ssh, vpn

I think in the past, say, if I run Ruby on Rails server (by using `rails s`) on a Bash which I ssh'ed to, and the Internet connection was interrupted, then

1. The Ruby on Rails server would stop
2. The Ruby on Rails server actually kept on running (I think it was due to the VPN disconnected), and I had to do a `ps ux` and then kill any related processes one by one... it was a bit messy.

Could either (1) or (2) happen? Is there a well defined behavior? For example, if it is not VPN but the ssh disconnected, then (1), but if it is VPN, then either (1) or (2)?

P.S. I have switched to using `tmux` if I have to run a Rails server on it, so that I can just come back and `tmux a -t foo` and attach back to it, and press CTRL-C if I need to.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the processes associated with the shell receive signal hup. They can ignore, if programmed that way. See man for `nohup`.

e.g. `nohup command` to run command so it won't get a hup. But also has stdin, stdout, stderr redirected.

See also `disown`, and `&`

to fully disconnect `nohup > /dev/null command & disown`